# Camera doesn't work on phone gap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to phone gap and I have built an app that works just fine on phone gap developer. But once I upload the app to phone gap build the camera stops working. I am using Android phone for testing.

Comment: phonegap developer app includes all the core plugins, but when uploading to phonegap build you have to configure the plugins on your config.xml

Comment: I have added the following lines in config file but still no luck


  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.2" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.3.3" />